# Running two scala functions in parallel, returning the latest value after 5 minutes

Tags: scala, future

I have two Scala functions that are expensive to run. Each one is like below, they start improving the value of a variable and I'd like to run them simultaneously and after 5 minutes (or some other time). I'd like to terminate the two functions and take their latest value up to that time.

```
def func1(n: Int): Double = {
   var a = 0.0D
   while (not terminated) {
       /// improve value of 'a' with algorithm 1 
   }
}

def func2(n: Int): Double = {
   var a = 0.0D
   while (not terminated) {
       /// improve value of 'a' with algorithm 2 
   }
}
```

I would like to know how I should structure my code for doing that and what is the best practice here? I was thinking about running them in two different threads with a timeout and return their latest value at time out. But it seems there can be other ways for doing that. I am new to Scala so any insight would be tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not hard. Here is one way of doing it:

```
  @volatile var terminated = false

  def func1(n: Int): Double = {
    var a = 0.0D
    while (!terminated) {
      a = 0.0001 + a * 0.99999; //some useless formula1
    }
    a
  }

  def func2(n: Int): Double = {
    var a = 0.0D
    while (!terminated) {
      a += 0.0001  //much simpler formula2, just for testing
    }
    a
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val f1 = Future { func1(1) } //work starts here

    val f2 = Future { func2(2) } //and here

    //aggregate results into one common future
    val aggregatedFuture = for{
      f1Result <- f1
      f2Result <- f2
    } yield (f1Result, f2Result)

    Thread.sleep(500) //wait here for some calculations in ms
    terminated = true //this is where we actually command to stop

    //since looping to while() takes time, we need to wait for results
    val res = Await.result(aggregatedFuture, 50.millis)
    //just a printout
    println("results:" + res)

 }
```

But, of course, you would want to maybe look at your while loops and create a more manageable and chainable calculations.

Output: `results:(9.999999999933387,31206.34691883926)`

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure if this is something you would want to do, but here is one approach (not for 5 minutes, but you can change that) :

```
object s
{
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println(run())

    def run(): (Int, Int) =
    {
        val (s, numNanoSec, seedVal) = (System.nanoTime, 500000000L, 0)
        Seq(f1 _, f2 _).par.map(f => 
        {
            var (i, id) = f(seedVal)
            while (System.nanoTime - s < numNanoSec)
            {
                i = f(i)._1
            }
            (i, id)
        }).seq.maxBy(_._1)
    }
    def f1(a: Int): (Int, Int) = (a + 1, 1)
    def f2(a: Int): (Int, Int) = (a + 2, 2)
}
```

Output:

```
me@ideapad:~/junk> scala s.scala 
(34722678,2)
me@ideapad:~/junk> scala s.scala 
(30065688,2)
me@ideapad:~/junk> scala s.scala 
(34650716,2)
```

Of course this all assumes you have at least two threads available to distribute tasks to.

Comment: This is better approach since it does not rely on side effects and is more in line with how usual code looks like. I tried to be more intuitive for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Future` with `Await` result to do that:

```
  def fun2(): Double = {
    var a = 0.0f
    val f = Future {
      // improve a with algorithm 2 
      a
    }
    try {
      Await.result(f, 5 minutes)
    } catch {
      case e: TimeoutException => a
    }
  }
```

use the `Await.result` to wait `algorithm` with timeout, when we met this timeout, we return the `a` directly